# Навигация по элементам enum class

Tags: c++, enum-class

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
enum class encl
{
  val1,
  val2,
  val3,
  val4,
  count
}
```

есть ли способ получить следующий элемент за, например, `val1`? для enum работало просто `val1 + 1`, теперь на это летит ошибка компиляции...

Comment: E operator+(E a, int v) {
   ...
}

Answer (score 4):

`encl(std::underlying_type_t<encl>(encl::val1) + 1)`.

В С++23 вместо `std::underlying_type_t<encl>(...)` есть `std::to_underlying(...)`.

Если лениво писать `underlying_type_t`, то вместо него можно поставить `int` (или другой тип - который указан в определении енума после `:`). Но это не по фен-шую, потому что:

- Можно поменять underlying тип в определении enum-а, а в кастах забыть поменять.
- Если `enum` обычный (не `enum class`), и для него не указан явно underlying type, и в нем есть крупные константы (не влезающие в `int`), то компилятор поставит underlying type крупнее чем `int`. Тогда касты к `int`у будут делать не то что нужно.

---

> для enum работало просто val1 + 1

Не особо работало. Оно возвращало не тип енума, а `int` (или какой-то другой целочисленный тип).

Comment: описка только: `encl::val1`… как же некоторые нововведения в с++ всё же упрощают жизнь ж)

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать функцию advance или перегрузить оператор инкремента например:

```
enum class encl
{
  val1,
  val2,
  val3,
  val4,
  count
};

inline encl & operator++(encl & value) noexcept
{
    switch(value)
    {
        case encl::val1:  value = encl::val2; break;
        case encl::val2:  value = encl::val3; break;
        case encl::val3:  value = encl::val4; break;
        case encl::val4:  value = encl::count; break;
        default: break;
    }
    return value;
}

#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    auto value{encl::val2};
    ++value;
    assert(encl::val3 == value);
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAzGakAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8baY9vkMQgRMxASZPn5cFVXptfUEhWGR0XoKdQ1N2a2DXT3FpRIAlLaoXsTI7ByMPgDUyAYKCuuMWyYaAIImAOxWx%2BvrAG5irYdHV7e0CQ9PYrGkbzdi0t9oXkEDzOABETLELidjsFaMFMHsGFt1uYAGzrVCJaJMIjEazWCD7WjIsxo55eTAzdYMVCYVTLRIEYHnb5XBQAd0IyAQEDJFJZyOZlyuwquoiUCK2IBAzy4IHe3nh4JBEtoUueZnBFnWEWImCYAGtNfyRWL4YS1WIzHKfgrkbFlebpR9NdrdQajUKRaKmOLHc9YtbeXaHYjVU7aJIXTq9YaIcbhaaVRaI4GxOTg0mUAsgRDXTGPY8vVcsFQmF5aAQ5dH3XHPQKwXXdQRFgwbeSC6DgcdzLFglsvFg7W4xUoGuDsF2jsECOsWExghAZkzISKy0Q25gzhY/ZbO7XC1c8ZZeQXVztogQCaHk7Fg0qN0v9yKmy31hoO6cG0cOHNVRwAKy8H4HBaKQqCcG4R5agoCxLIqZixDwpCViBP5zPqID/ho%2BicJIQGaLw4EcLwCggNhKFaHMcCwDAiBZiwiR0NE5CUGgDFMTEWyGMAXCxBo2E0BW0SkRAEQEaQETBPUACenBIWxbCCAA8gwtCyahpBYHORjiBp%2BC6g4eDXJgpEabSmDIF4BArKB06VOJsI6jJHhYOJBDEHgLByT%2BfAGMACgAGp4JgbJKZiwFIfwggiGI7BSDIgiKCo6gaborQGEYKBQfoeARKRkBzBi1SmQAtCVgzoEqpiWNYXCnOsJUAOpiESTW0u5TANY1mLoIYjjIF10TECQJGVBZ1QuAw7ieM0/hTZMfQxK0uRpAIIwtEkKSrQwC0lP0YxjYZAidMMM2jG040dEM3RwlM%2B22Nd60DNdu3TFwcwwYsyx6O5mArDwv6cIBpDAaBRGqAAHCiJUopImwZcA6y8QAdBoqPrBAkE1ZYpDrLghAkMSiG4x47H0MQRPvbwFFoaQGFYThHB4aQXkM6DhGcCRZHIQRVG0RASALAQiRWSxEBsYx5P%2BPgOJ6FFwiiOI8Xy0lahubq/28GyxBMIk3mAwB%2BEaURSlWSLM6oFQ6yQ9DsPw9xSOxKj6OY6gZPRJTMzU7zcwIHqWAxIujPM6z2Hs2BnO2NzNMzOhmHYX%2BsRG2DkcxwbZjJxzxE86hsekMZxCpM4khAA%3D%3D)